# ConverTo-Json altering intended output

Tags: powershell, convertto-json

I have a psobject that is created from the JSON output of an Invoke-RestMethod.  My intention is to change one value, convert back to JSON, then add back to the application REST API with another Invoke-RestMethod.  I have done this several times in the past with the same REST API so I'm not sure why this one isn't working.

The psobject `$restOut` looks like this:

```
id: 123
limit: @{limitMb=0; limitPercent=0}
```

The next block of code changes the id if the new id I want isn't already set

```
$newId = 456
if($restOut.id -ne $newId){
   $restOut.id = $newId
   $inputJson = $restOut | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2
   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restURl -Method PUT -Body $inputJson
}
```

I'm expecting `$inputJson` to look like this (and the psobject `$restOut` does match the expectation):

```
{
   "id": "456",
   "limit": {
               "limitMb": 0,
               "limitPercent": 0
            }
}
```

But what I'm actually getting is:

```
{
   "id":  {
             "value": "456",
             "id": "456"
          },
   "limit": {
               "limitMb": 0,
               "limitPercent": 0
            }
}
```

As said, I've done this exact manipulation many times in other scripts targeting the same software API, and am just at a loss with the behavior this time.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix

This was a simplified sample.  In my actual script `$newId = 456` was actually being assigned from another API call.  Therefore it was also an object.  Simply quoting it in the line that changes the id to make it a string fixed the issue:

```
$restOut.id = "$newId"
```

instead of

```
$restOut.id = $newId
```